# VBA to Sum a Column from a fixed cell up until the first blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of numeric data, where I need to sum the values from a specified cell, down to the last value before the first blank cell in the Column. I have used a Range function previously to complete this, but on this occasion the number of rows before the blank cell is unknown and cannot be defined in a range. the simple explanation is I need the result in cell `A1` to be

```
=sum (A6:AX)
```

where `X` is one before the first blank cell.

I will then write this into my VBA loop to complete it for nth columns over nth sheets.

Comment: Try: `WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A6:A" & Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following sub:

```
Sub SumTillBlankCell()
Dim BeforeFirstBlankCell

  BeforeFirstBlankCell = Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row
  Range("A1").Value = Application.Sum(Range("A6:A" & BeforeFirstBlankCell))

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great thanks worked like a charm. How would I divide that value by 2 without significantly changing the code? I am reaching my kb limit in this particular function.

Comment: If you want to divide by 2 then use this formula `Range("A1").Value = Application.Sum(Range("A6:A" & BeforeFirstBlankCell))/2`